# How to overwrite values in a Python dictonary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this example:

```
    d = {}
    x = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
    above = ['abovekey1', 'abovekey2']

    for ak in above:
        d[ak] = x
        d[ak]['key2'] = str(ak)
```

The output of d is:

```
{'abovekey1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'abovekey2'},
 'abovekey2': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'abovekey2'}}
```

But I wrote the code to expect this output:

```
{'abovekey1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'abovekey1'},
 'abovekey2': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'abovekey2'}}
```

How can I change the code to yield the output that I am expecting and what am I missing in the above example?

Thank you all!

Comment: You're putting multiple references to `x` inside `d`. If you want them to be different, you want to copy `x` as you put it in `d`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, `d[ak] = x` references the same dictionary. You can achieve desired result by making a copy of `x`:

```
x = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
above = ['abovekey1', 'abovekey2']

d = {k: dict(x, key2=k)  for k in above}
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'abovekey1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'abovekey1'}, 'abovekey2': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'abovekey2'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy of `x` use `.copy`

**Ex:**

```
d = {}
x = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
above = ['abovekey1', 'abovekey2']

for ak in above:
    d[ak] = x.copy()
    d[ak]['key2'] = ak
    
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'abovekey1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'abovekey1'},
 'abovekey2': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'abovekey2'}}
```

Comment: Incredible, I would have never ever found the solution. As I am working with nested dicts, I need a deepcopy and found the solution for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474959/nested-dictionaries-copy-or-deepcopy

Answer (score 0):

In python, objects are never implicitly copied but instead referenced. If you want to edit a separate dictionary, you need to copy it first.

Beware: the `.copy()` operation makes a *shallow copy* of a dictionary. If your dictionary has more hierarchy levels/nested dicts and you want to copy all of them, you need to make a *deep copy* using `.deepcopy()`. For this you need to import it first

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html for more info on shallow vs. deep copy.