# Dictionary value not getting updated

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, discord.py

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours in my discord bot, and have found something that makes me even more confused, can anyone tell me if I'm doing anything wrong? Data is a dictionary loaded from a data file, that contains keys of user id's, and the value of those user id's are dictionaries with info about the user. e.g. It doesn't seem like the dictionary is being updated...

```
data = {
    528904852321: {'pocket_money': 1000},
    085984902543: {'pocket_money': 1000},
}
```

```
print(data[robberid]['pocket_money']) # 1000
print(data[victimid]['pocket_money']) # 1000

amount = 50
print(amount) # 50

data[robberid]['pocket_money'] -= amount
data[victimid]['pocket_money'] += amount

print(data[robberid]['pocket_money']) # 1000
print(data[victimid]['pocket_money']) # 1000
```

Comment: Can you please share your code to this?

Comment: This is definitely not reproducible, more code is needed to identify the problem

Comment: I'm not sure stackoverflow would like my pasting 1k lines of code in here, however I have some more info about it; I have my dictionary 'data', and when I'm writing to a nested dictionary in data it seems to write to all of the dictionaries in the data, do you have any idea what it could be? @Ceres

Comment: You don't need to provide all 1000 lines here, just the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: nvm, got it fixed

Comment: Great, you can post the solution here if it is relevant or delete the question if you want to.

Comment: This guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474959/nested-dictionaries-copy-or-deepcopy fixed the issue.